# Is there a Visual Studio Code command for hiding the scroll bar on one of the editors upon an editor being split?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a VSC command that is related to hiding the scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove Minimap:**

```
View->Show Minimap
```

**Remove the Overview Ruler:**

Add the following to your settings.json file

```
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": true
```

This will keep the scrollbar, but will result in it only appearing when the cursor is within the editor.

**Completely remove scrollbars (requires restart):**

If you would like to completely remove the scrollbars, add the following to your settings.json file (the editor may say "Unknown configuration setting" - ignore this. It will still work):

```
"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"
```

This will result in the scrollbars not being visible even when the cursor is in the editor.

Comment: Do you know if there is a workbench command that exists?

Comment: I don't know of a direct menu option to do this in the current version of VSCode. But I have tested what I showed above for completely remove scrollbars and it works.

One easy way to get to the settings.json file is to open Settings (ctrl+,) then click on the small icon in the top right that looks like a page of paper with a curved arrow on it.